# Bootstrap: How can I put a line break between the textarea and button?

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

This is the bootstrap page

```
<div id="cover-caption">
<div id="container" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row d-flex">
<div class="col-lg-10 offset-sm-1 text-center"><br>
<h1 class ="font-weight-bold">Classes</h1>
<div class="info-form">
<form action="" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Class Name">
</div><br>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
</div><br>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
<br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#cover {
  background: #222 url('') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
 }

 #cover-caption {
 width: 100%;
 }
```

I want to put a line break between the textarea and button, and `<br>` doesn't work. Can someone explain why and help me fix it

Comment: I work, https://jsfiddle.net/MatrixTai/d8ymL17g/, you need to provide more code.

Comment: @MatrixTai ok.. is this good?

Comment: ...You need to make the problem reproducible, when asking html related question, it is convenient to use snippet provided by stackoverflow or jsfiddle liked website as I provided. Indeed, you problem probably come from CSS which you didn't provide, try make a sample using those tool, or no one could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `<hr>` ? or simply `<br><br>` ?

Or you could put `style="padding-top: 10px;"` on the button...

Have a great day.

**EDIT:**

removed form-inline class from form tag, replaced with span (you'll need to fix the centering):

```
<div id="cover-caption">
        <div id="container" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row d-flex">
                <div class="col-lg-10 offset-sm-1 text-center">
                    <br>
                    <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Classes</h1>
                    <div class="info-form">
                        <form action="">
                            <span class="form-inline justify-content-center">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Class Name">
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </span>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" style="padding-top: 10px;">Submit</button>

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out

Comment: all good, edited my answer again to fix the centering issue (moved justify-content-center into the span).  Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I finally understand your problem.

You are letting the bootstrap CSS form to override your button. You dun need to change anything instead just put the button outside the form.

```
<form action="" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Class Name">
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title">
  </div><br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>
```

Comment: wish i could accept both answers since they both work

Comment: @KuldeepChoudhary You can use `form=""` flag in the html, or using js to submit it.

Comment: @MT-FreeHK yes that can be possible - but still not good practice to add submit button outside the form

Comment: @KuldeepChoudhary Why it is not a good practice, can you explain a little bit?

Comment: @MT-FreeHK
1. This will not work without JS (Normal form submit will not work)
2. Still if we do this through js - this form input boxes will not support onSubmit event - 
Like when you click enter btn on any input box - form will not trigger onSubmit event - only have to click on Submit button.
If we put this btn inside - it on entry click form will trigger onSubmit event -

Comment: 1. You can use `form="myFormId"` for the button outside the form. 2. It is the benefit when you don't want the default `onSubmit` behavior. || As long as no security flaw, I think it is acceptable.